# How do I find the derivative of $2e^{-x}+e^{5x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$2e^{-x}+e^{5x}$$

Here is what I have tried: $$2e^{-x}+e^{5x}$$
$$\frac{2}{e^x}+e^{5x}$$
$$\left(\frac{2}{e^x}\right)'+(e^{5x})'$$

$$\left(\frac{2}{e^x}\right)' = \frac{-2e^x}{e^{2x}}$$
$$(e^{5x})'=5xe^{5x}$$

So the answer I got was $$\frac{-2e^x}{e^{2x}}+5xe^{5x}$$

I checked my answer online and it said that it was incorrect but I am sure I have done the steps correctly. Did I approach this problem correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{ax})=ae^{ax}$$
(this works for negative values of $a$ too, so no need to make your life more complicated with the quotient rule)

Comment: Could you elaborate how this works with negatives? I know the power rule where $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$. However the exponent isn't a number, how would I subtract that?

Comment: The function $e^x$ is not a power of $x$, so the power rule is irrelevant...

Comment: I believe my professor said something about this and I may have missed it. Would you mind explaining what it is? I also know that $(e^x)' = lne*e^x$, is that the rule I use?

Comment: What you've written is a correct statement, but needlessly complicated since (by definition)
$$\ln(e)=1.$$
Perhaps you're thinking of the more general formula
$$\frac{d}{dx}(a^x)=\ln(a)a^x.$$
Unfortunately this is not helpful in your current problem. Incidentally, you can see that it is obtainable from the formula
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{bx})=be^{bx}$$
because, if we let $b=\ln(a)$, we have
$$a^x=(e^{\ln(a)})^x=e^{\ln(a)x}$$
so that
$$\frac{d}{dx}(a^x)=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\ln(a)x})=\ln(a)e^{\ln(a)x}=\ln(a)a^x.$$

Comment: Ahh thank you! I was wondering where that rule came from.

Comment: Glad to help!${}$

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra $x$ in the second term.  $(e^{5x})'=5e^{5x}$ by the chain rule.  I suspect the online check might prefer $-2e^{-x}$ for the first term, but your version is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Not correct: $(e^{5x})'\neq 5xe^{5x}$

$$(e^{5x})' = 5e^{5x}$$

$$(ae^{bx})' = abe^{bx}$$

It's because of the chain rule, and because $\frac d{dx}(e^x) = e^x$.

Comment: See the [chain rule, composites of functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Composites_of_more_than_two_functions)

Answer (score 0):

derivative of $2e^{-x} = -2e^{-x}$

derivative  of $e^{5x} = 5e^{5x}$

**In general the derivative of $e^{ax} = ae^{ax}$, where $a$ is a constant.**

Comment: Missing a in the exponent ?

Comment: yea ! overlooked it ! thanks anyways !!